# Open Ip in Google Chrome from Applescript

Tags: url, shell, browser, applescript, ip

I've been trying to get applescript to open an ip using a shell script in both Google Chrome and safari, but alack no success. So far I've been trying the open command like this:

```
do shell script "open http://" & blockedIP
```

which works when I substitute blockedIP for a URL, but when I try and use an IP it just opens a new tab with the default homepage and the IP in the address bar. I've tried a couple other methods as well but each one either doesn't work at all or does the same as this one. Anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
tell application "Safari"
    make new document at end of documents
    set URL of document 1 to "http://" & blockedIP
end tell
```

This doesn't use a shell script to do the work, it uses direct Safari AppleScripting (because it's scriptable.)
If you want to do the same on Google Chrome, then use:

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    make new window with properties {mode:"normal"}
    set URL of active tab of window 1 to "http://" & blockedIP
end tell
```